# Hosting on GitHub Pages Throwing 404 Error

Tags: github, github-pages, pixi.js

I am trying to host the following on GitHub pages: https://github.com/KamiFightingSpirit/CompleteDrafts

However upon clicking on the github pages provided link https://kamifightingspirit.github.io/CompleteDrafts/ 
I am getting a 404 error. This site is using the Pixi.js library and it works fine via my command line "python -m http.server 3000"

Sorry that I can't provide more details, I just don't know anything more that would be helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be 404 anymore. It takes a while to update sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the repository name to your `username.github.io`.

So if my username is `'helloworld'`,
change repository name to `helloworld.github.io`.